# Parsing into dictionary with regex as separator for splitting

Tags: c#, .net, regex

As I said in title, I think the idea would be to split it by something like this`\d+?=.*?\d=` but not quite sure... Any idea how best to parse this string:

`1=Some dummy sentence
2=Some other sentence  3=Third sentence which can be in the same line
4=Forth sentence
some text which shouldn't be captured and spplitted`

And what I'm hoping to get from this is a Dictionary which will have this number for key, and this string in the value, so for example:

`1, "Some dummy sentence"
2, "Some other sentence"
3, "Third sentence which can be in the same line"
4, "Forth sentence"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method to parse text into dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetValuesToDictionary(string text)
{
    var pattern = @"(\d+)=(.*?)((?=\d=)|\n)";
    //If spaces between digit and equal sign are possible then (\d+)\s*=\s*(.*?)((?=\d\s?=)|\n)
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);

    var pairs = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    var matches = regex.Matches(text);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        var key = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        var value = match.Groups[2].Value;
        if (!pairs.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            pairs.Add(key, value);
        }
        //pairs.Add(key, value);
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

In this case i check if lkey already exists and if so i do not add it but you can see for yourself if you need this check.
Includes digit groups without equal sign in the value.

Comment: This works almost as I wonted, how this regex can be modified to also stop at \r\n ? Because for last matched item it takes also the content from the row bellow...

Comment: I think I corrected that in the last edit. See the edited regex.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that :) Works like a charm! Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: Ha, I found one more test case ` 0=Level 0  1=Level 1  2=Level 2` it looks like it separates them at first number after = and not at {number}= or \n

Comment: If you use digits like that here is another regex "(\d+)=(.*?)((?=\d=?)|\n)" but because you use dictionary to store the pairs some values may not be kept in the dictionary if key already exists. If you have pair with 0 and "zero" and pair with 0 and "zerozero" you will keep only the first one matched. To match them all you will need to use Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> and when you add pair: pairs.Add(key, new HasSet<string>),when you add only value: pairs[key].Add(value)

Comment: But the thing is that for value you can have number in the string, so I don't want to change the dictionary type, so Dictionary<int, string> is fine, just for some values where I have number I want to be able to have something like this for the result: 0, Level 0; 1, Level 1; 2, Level 2 instead of this http://prntscr.com/d6l2wq where value is just "Level"

Comment: Sorry,my bad. (\d+)=(.*?)((?=\d=)|\n) will include digits now.

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to type you that, you can update your answer (code), this works with all test cases that I have now.
Also this code from bellow also work with minor modification `\n?(\d)=(.*?)(?=\d\=|\n)`, too bad I can't accept both answers here :)

Comment: In the case when spaces between digit and equal sign should be considered the regex will be (\d+)\s*=\s*(.*?)((?=\d\s?=)|\n)

Answer (score 1):

What about this: https://regex101.com/r/6ED8Om/2

```
\n?(\d+)=(.*?)(?= *\d|\n)
```

- `\n?(\d+)=` matches optional new line character followed by digits and equal sign
- `(.*?)` matches following text
- `(?= *\d|\n)` matches any number of spaces followed by a digit, or a new line character. The spaces prevent #2 to include the two spaces between its end end #3

EDIT: Use other answer code with this regex to save your values to a dictionnary. Group 1 matches the digits, group 2 matches the text.

Comment: Thanks for good regex explanation, I was close with my initial regex, but again far from working version... :)

Comment: Can this be modified somehow to capture the value also if there's a number inside? For example like here https://regex101.com/r/6ED8Om/3 where also "Test where we have number 5 in the value" should be captured as value. Nvm, It's like this `\n?(\d)=(.*?)(?=\d\=|\n)` :)